# Как запустить графическую оболочку в Android x86

Tags: android, x86

После установки Android x86 не загружается графическая оболочка. Как загрузить графическую оболочку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам надо запустить графический сервер командой `startx`

Comment: `startx: not found`.

Comment: ну значит у вас установка прошла не успешно, система не скопировала все файлы до конца на загрузочный носитель. попробуйте вариант автоустановкой ( авторазбивкой диска ).